# Alerts for social notes

Tags: alert, publishing-page, social

I am to develop an alert system for the social notes functionality in SharePoint 2010. I could write a timer job looping through all pages and look for new notes since last run, or loop through all users. But this would be a rather time consuming timer job. Is there some way to get all notes in one operation for all urls and users. Even better would be if I could hook on to note events when they are created, thus not requiring a timerjob, is there a way to do this? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a timer job which loops through all pages and checks for new notes.

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box activity feed displays all the latest social notes. I would suggest looking at the timerjob code for an example of how it gathers the information to publish the activity events.

Comment: If I am correct the activity feed only displays social notes relevant to me,based on social distance etc. Unfortunatly most of the code relevant to Social is marked as internal.